# How to find all the LDAP groups that a user is part of, when groupOfUniqueNames is used to define groups

Tags: php, ldap

When I connect to the LDAP server and retrieve the user, I get the correct user record, but I don't see any memberOf, isMemberOf or any other similar attribute that tells me what groups they are in:

```
$query = "(&(uid={$username})(objectClass=person))";
$result = ldap_search($ldapconnection, $context, $query);
$user = ldap_get_entries($ldapconnection, $result);
```

However, If I retrieve the LDAP group, then I can see a list of users that includes all the right ones:

```
$query = "(&({cn=".$groupname.")(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames))";
$result = ldap_search($ldapconnection, $context, $query);
$group = ldap_get_entries($ldapconnection, $result); // Users in array attribute
```

The groups are dynamic groupOfUniqueNames ones, and each user is a uniqueMember of the group.

Am I missing something, or is the server not configured to show memberOf (MS AD)? Is there any way to get the memberships for a particular user without looping over every single group there is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're not getting the memberOf attribute back from your queries, but you should be able to retrieve a user's group membership with something like this:

```
$query = "(&(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=" . $username . "))";
```

It looks like uniqueMember is not indexed by default (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680520(v=vs.85).aspx), so if you have access to do so, and run into performance issues, it might be worth indexing it.

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to get it working with this, but had to include the user's full DN as the $username.